# How to create a global variable? How to access it from views and services?

Tags: playframework

Say I want to access `val nbPhotosDisplayed: Int = 3` from views and services (maybe controllers in the future). How would I go about that?
I thought creating an `object` in its own file like this would do the trick (Infos is in the default package):

```
object Infos {
  val nbPhotosDisplayed: Int = 3
}
```

When trying to access Infos.nbPhotosDisplayed from views and services I get a compilation error saying Infos is unknown.

**EDIT:** this is the error I get:

```
[error] /home/simonlbc/workspace/jbWeb/server/app/services/CssModifier.scala:33: not found: value Infos
[error]   val replacement = prefix+"{ width:"+100.0/Infos.nbPhotosDisplayed+"%;}"
[error]                                             ^
[error] /home/simonlbc/workspace/jbWeb/server/app/views/photos.scala.html:18: not found: value Infos
[error]         val content = (0 until Infos.nbPhotosDisplayed).map {
[error]                                ^
```

Comment: What about the package? Also please provide some more information such as the exact error message.

Comment: @rethab What I meant previously was that Infos was in the default package. I added the compilation errors I am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is happening because of no package for object Infos, when I moved it under `app/utils`, everything starts work for me perfectly.

To be honest, I'm not sure what causes the troubles with no package. May be some Twirl/Play internals.

Comment: Yes that was it, thank you. I just had to create a directory in app called utils. Put the file containing the Infos object in utils. Put `package utils` at the beginning of that file. And then add `import util.Infos` in every scala or scala.html files where I used an attribute of Info in it.